# Word Javascript API: General exception from length/complexity of regular expression

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm doing a full-text search of a Word document body where I perform several searches consecutively. They are all similar, but searching for slightly different patterns. The most complex of them throws a general exception at context.load(searchResults ...

I've isolated the problem using Script Lab to Character Group use (square brackets). If I use seven character groups, the search succeeds. If I add an eighth, a general exception is thrown. This is consistent even if I simplify everything else about the expression, as in this string that should find the word "Chapters".

If I scale back sSearchString to:

```
 var sSearchString = '[Chapters][Chapters][Chapters][Chapters][Chapters][Chapters][Chapters]';
```

... it works and finds the word "Chapter" with no "s". But if I just add one more Character Group on the end:

```
 var sSearchString = '[Chapters][Chapters][Chapters][Chapters][Chapters][Chapters][Chapters][Chapters]';
```

... it produces a general exception.

Is anyone familiar with this limitation of the MS JavaScript API? Does anyone have any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in the [Script Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab) tool?

Comment: Yes. Seems like the same error. Sorry I'm getting back to this late. I had found a workaround and forgotten about this until I encountered it again.

Comment: Actually the Script Lab tool has helped me isolate the issue, as reflected in my edit above. Apparently there is a hard limit of seven sets of square bracketed character groups in a regular expression. Add one more, you get a general exception.